# Chained select not working with server

Tags: javascript, html

The below given select is working fine with http://jsfiddle.net/FWsX7/254/. But while i put in html file and running with server, its not working. Why is that? Is there any problem with window.onload function?

```
<label>Car</label>
<select id="car"> 
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="suzuki">Suzuki</option>
</select> 

<label>city</label>
    <select id="city"> 
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = (function() {

    var locations = {
        'bmw': [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            ],
        'audi': [
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            ],
        'suzuki': [
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            ],
    };

    var cars = document.getElementById('car');
    var cities = document.getElementById('city');

    cars.addEventListener('change', function() {
        loadCities(this.value)
    }, false)


    var loadCities = (function loadCitiesFunc(key) {
        key = key || 'bmw';
        var docFragment = document.createElement('select');
        for (var i = 0; i < locations[key].length; i++) {
            docFragment.appendChild(new Option(locations[key][i], locations[key][i]));
        }
        cities.innerHTML = docFragment.innerHTML;

        return loadCitiesFunc;
    }())



}());
```

Comment: Are you adding (JQuery)[<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>] Library to your HTML file?

Comment: There is no jQuery used in here, what made you put this tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` needs a *callback*. You are supplying a function that is executed immediately (an *immediately invoked function expression* (aka [iffe](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/))). That may or may not work, dependent on the page rendering (speed, script tag position etc.). Remove a few parentheses. So use: `window.onload = function () { ...}`

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the parenthesis mismatch at last 
in your java script add lines at last  it will work fine

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the onload function to execute code. If it is relative to positions or if loading the page takes longer than 200 ms i would recommend making the initial onload function an individual function that is triggered by

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        initFunc();
    }
</script>
```

possibly at the end of your HTML.
Of course this requires jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without using jQuery also.
Your problem is this function getting called before the DOM has loaded.

```js
document.querySelector('body').onload = function () {
  
  var locations = {
        'bmw': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'audi': ['4', '5', '6'],
        'suzuki': ['7', '8', '9']
    };

    var cars = document.getElementById('car');
    var cities = document.getElementById('city');

    cars.addEventListener('change', function() {
        loadCities(this.value)
    }, false);


    var loadCities = (function loadCitiesFunc(key) {
        key = key || 'bmw';
        var docFragment = document.createElement('select');
        for (var i = 0; i < locations[key].length; i++) {
            docFragment.appendChild(new Option(locations[key][i], locations[key][i]));
        }
        cities.innerHTML = docFragment.innerHTML;
        return loadCitiesFunc;
    }());
  
 };
```

```html
<label>Car</label>
<select id="car"> 
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="suzuki">Suzuki</option>
</select> 

<label>city</label>
    <select id="city"> 
</select>
```